# hostpolicy.dll not found when trying to launch .net core wpf app using process.start

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have a .net 3.0 WPF application called client.

I have a second .net core 3.0 application called launcher.

I am trying to launch the client application from launcher.

```
var filename = @$"Client.exe";
var child = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo()
{
  UseShellExecute = true,
  FileName = filename,
});
```

When I run  this, I get an error from client.exe

```
A fatal error was encountered. The library 'hostpolicy.dll' required to execute the application was not found in 'C:\Program Files\dotnet'.
```

edit: I can launch a console app, so I think the problem is related to the fact that I'm trying to launch a WPF app.